# What is the solution to this difficult yet simple looking integral that wolfram alpha can't solve?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

For a bit of context this integral came up during my studies for multivariate analysis. It is a seemingly simple looking integral that has blocked all attempts to pry into its secrets.

$\int \ln(x)^{\exp(x)} dx$

I've attempted to use tricks like $u$-substitutions and integration by parts. I've even derived a formula for $\frac{d f(x)^{g(x)}}{dx}$ and attempted to use that with no good results. The u-subs themselves were $u = e^x$ and $u = \ln(x)$ and they did not lead in good directions. Giving other janky integrals that were difficult to solve. Wolfram alpha did not give me any hints either and at this point I am considering using the tools I've learned in multivariable analysis, taking a page out of the $\int \exp(-x^2) dx$ playbook and mashing some coordinate system onto it to bruteforce a solution. Please help me.

Comment: Just to be clear, $\ln(x)$ raised to $e^x$, or $\ln\left(x^{e^x}\right)$? Power+log notation can be misleading sometimes.

Comment: It is precisely $ln(x)$ raised to $e^x$.

Comment: Probably Wolfram Alpha can prove that the antiderivate has no closed form. The Risch-algorithm does that. Why do you think this integral is easy ? We are even screwed if we want to integrate , say , $\sin(x^2)$

Comment: To be clear, I never said the integral was easy (I would have solved it myself had it been an easy integral). Just that it looked simple, which it does, same as $sin(x^2)$ looks deceivingly simple. I am sorry if my wording was inflammatory to you, for I never meant it to be. Simple was simply the best word I had to describe it. I was trying to convey how easy it was to stumble into this integral.

Comment: Would a solution in terms of a series expansion work?

Comment: I don't think that expression has an elementary antiderivative, or at least according to online calculators. I would be shocked if it did.

Comment: If this one had a solution, the somophore dream would be a piece of cake  since it is the same as $$\int e^t \,t^{e^{e^t}}\,dt$$